# WPF Cefsharp google login

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I know that google login for cefsharp has been blocked for long time now,
but is there any way to bypass this
for example calling a actual chrome browser for the login and get the access token

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately there's no example of logging in using the system browser. I reached to Google when they started blocking logins and never got a response. Others had similar experiences https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/embedder-dev/c/STyM5ZNTHMM/m/POj1v_cqBgAJ hacky workarounds like changing the useragent have worked previously. Google are blocking all embedded browsers now, so not just a CEF specific limitation.

Comment: For reference https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/guidance-for-our-effort-to-block-less-secure-browser-and-apps.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add at the end of your UserAgent `/CefSharp Browser" + Cef.CefSharpVersion;`
Example :

```
settings.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36 /CefSharp Browser" + Cef.CefSharpVersion;
```

And it work...